# Print lines with double quotes using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

**Input file:**

```
line1 column1  column2 column3 column4 
line2 "column1"  column2 column3 column4
line3 column1  column2 column3 column4
line4 column1  "column2 column3" column4
line5 column1  column2 column3 column4
```

**Needed output using awk:**

```
line2 "column1"  column2 column3 column4
line4 column1  "column2 column3" column4
```

So basically I need to display all lines with double quotes using awk: 
My command fails  **awk 'NF{$0=" "}' inputfile.txt**

Answer (score 6):

NF checks the number of fields.  You probably need:

```
awk '/"/' inputfile.txt
```

The default action is to print the line; the pattern looks for a double quote anywhere on the line.  Alternatively, use `grep '"' inputfile.txt` instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to match lines in a file you should go with `grep` first:

```
$ grep '"' file
line2 "column1"  column2 column3 column4
line4 column1  "column2 column3" column4
```

Equivalently with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/"/' file
line2 "column1"  column2 column3 column4
line4 column1  "column2 column3" column4
```